# Iterate over all modules in a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm a bit confused by the variables available inside the Kernel. How would I go about iterating over all modules inside my own kernel module? I found `modules` being used in the kernel code. Can I do something along the lines of

```
struct module *mod;

list_for_each_entry(mod, &modules, list) {
  printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", mod->name);
}
```

Comment: You cannot: `modules` is a **static** variable, defined in [kernel/module.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L96), this variable cannot be used outside of this file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Any alternative symbol I could use? I'm looking for something like `init_task`or any other way to print loaded modules?

Comment: I found `modules_list` in [drivers/staging/greybus/audio_manager.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/greybus/audio_manager.c#L33) but I literally cannot find where it came from

Comment: Looks like you cannot print list of modules *directly*: there is `print_module()` function, declared in `linux/module.h`, but this function is not exported for modules (with `EXPORT_SYMBOL()`). If you want to get the list just for debugging purposes, you may use `WARN_ON` macro: if condition fails, then it prints list of modules among other information. As for file `drivers/staging/greybus/audio_manager.c`, it uses other type of "module", completely unrelated to `struct module`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So I assume what `audio_manager` is referencing is this [kernel/ksyms.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ksyms.c?v=2.2.26#L448)? I would potentially be able to get the symbol address for a System call named `print_modules`. I can't find reference to what it does though...

Comment: @Tsyvarev btw. thanks for the help so far. I can't get my testing machine running for now so I'm coding blind here.

Comment: `audio_manager` refers to variable `modules_list` declared *statically* [in the same source file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/greybus/audio_manager.c#L21). This variable isn't related with 'modules' variable declared in `kernel/module.c`.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no direct way** for iterate over list of modules.

Head of the module's list is `modules` variable, which is *statically* defined in [kernel/module.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L96), so it is not accessible for code outside of this file.

---

If list of module's name is needed for *debugging purposes*, you may use WARN_ON() macro or similar:

```
WARN_ON(0);
```

this will print message about warning and some additional information, which among other things will contain list of modules.

Answer (score -1):

Found a workaround to solve this.

```
struct list_head *list;
struct module *mod;
struct module *mine = find_module("YOUR_MODULE_NAME");

list_for_each(list, &mine->list){
  mod = list_entry(list, struct module, list);
  do_stuff_with_mod(mod);
}
```

This uses the method `find_module` from [kernel/module](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L609). You will need to specify your module to be licensed under GPL or otherwise it will fail to load (compilation will be successful though).

#### Disclaimer

I don't think this method is the best approach but it is solid enough to work with simple tasks like `printk`

Comment: 1. You can get `struct module` for your kernel module simply by using `THIS_MODULE` macro. No need for find_module() here.

Comment: 2. If you traverse the list of modules, you better do this with `module_mutex` locked. Otherwise some list items may disappear while you process them (if some modules are unloaded), which might result in a kernel crash.

Comment: While this "workaround" may work sometimes, it generally **wrong**: `list_for_each()` expects **head of the list** passed as the second parameter. And `mine->list` is not a head, but a *list's element*. As a result, one element in your iteration is not a module, and shouldn't be passed to `list_entry()` function.