# List kernel modules

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

I write kernel module which lists all modules loaded in system. But when is end list of modules, loop are working. I tried everything to stop this loop, but finally I cant do this. I added function printk which write module name (it makes kernel [oops](http://tniesz.pl/qbsyg) when tries write name module which doesn`t exist). Can anyone help me? I need list of modules to continue write this module. Source:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/list.h>

struct list_head modules_list;
struct list_head *m;
struct module *ops_mod;
int agh = 0;
char *x = (char) 0;

void list_module(void)
{
  modules_list = THIS_MODULE->list;
  for(m = (&modules_list)->next; m != (&modules_list); m = m->next) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "List iteration %d", agh);
    ops_mod = list_entry(m, struct module, list);
    if ((m)->next == NULL) {
      printk(KERN_WARNING "MISC list: NULL pointer");
      return;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "after iteration %d", agh);
    printk(KERN_INFO "print name %d", agh);
    agh++;
    if (&ops_mod->mkobj.kobj.name == NULL)
      return;
    else {
        printk("Adress: %d", ops_mod);
        printk("MISC: ok %s", ops_mod->mkobj.kobj.name);
      }
    //ops_mod = NULL;
  }
}

int init_module(void)
{
  list_module();
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: The something is wrong with your end of loop condition (`m != (&modules_list)`). is this a circular list?

Comment: I dont know. Its global modules list

Comment: Proper way for iterate over list is using `list_for_each()`, `list_for_each_entry()` or similar macro. But all these macros requires **head of the list**, and you have no access to it (see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558217/iterate-over-all-modules-in-a-kernel-module). `THIS_MODULE->list` is an *element of the list*, not a head.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd hold `module_mutex`, and use a list helper, something like this:

```
struct module *mod;
mutex_lock(&module_mutex);
list_for_each_entry(mod, &THIS_MODULE->list, list)
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s", mod->name);
mutex_unlock(&module_mutex);
```

But you're doing this from within `init_module`, so I think the issue may be that your module isn't set up yet.

Comment: Oh, but @Tsyvarev is right, and the flaw is actually that it is not possible to traverse the list starting from the current module.